# maker-bundle custom skeleton (symfony 4)

Tags: php, symfony4

I would like to replace maker-bundle template by my own template skeleton https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/tree/master/src/Resources/skeleton/crud

In sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle (SF3) it was easy, we just have to copy/paste into Ressources directory the customized skeleton.

I didn't find how to do same rendering with maker-bundle.

Do I have to build my own maker ? Others solutions ? It seems to be a common problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that template overriding is not an option right now. What you could do is to create a new maker command that is based on `make:crud` and provide your own path to your templates.

Check this part of a documentation to see how to create a new maker command https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#creating-your-own-makers